# how to install face_recognition module for python

Tags: python, cmake, pip, face-recognition, dlib

i have installed the cmake but still dlib is not installing which is required for the installation of face_recognition module

the below mentioned error i am getting whenever i try to install the dlib by using the pip install dlib

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2fd_0qt9' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
    Generator

      NMake Makefiles

    does not support platform specification, but platform

      x64

    was specified.


  CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/sunil/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-oufh_gcl/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\sunil\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-89jcoq15\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      Generator

        NMake Makefiles

      does not support platform specification, but platform

        x64

      was specified.


    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/sunil/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-oufh_gcl/dlib/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\sunil\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.7', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\sunil\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sunil\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oufh_gcl\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-89jcoq15\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\sunil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oufh_gcl\dlib\
```

can anyone tell me the easiest way to install the face_recognition module for my windows 10

Answer (score 3):

**If you have conda installed in your system then follow these steps:**

- conda create -n py36 python=3.6
- activate py36
- conda config --add channels conda-forge
- conda install numpy
- conda install scipy
- conda install dlib
- pip install --no-dependencies face_recognition

Answer (score 2):

First of all, install Cmake.

```
pip install cmake
```

After that, install the dlib.

If pip is not working, install dlib via the wheel file.

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
```

After that, you can install the face_regognition module.

```
pip install face_recognition
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Cmake with:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```

And for python3 don't use pip alone, use pip3 to install future python3 modules:

```
pip3 install face_recognition
```

Comment: still getting the same error and the above cmake command is for linux and i have windows

Comment: please watch out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4_M8YTAPDg&feature=youtu.be . that may be useful for you

Comment: thank you sir, it is useful in installing the dlib in anaconda

Answer (score 0):

if your OS is windows7 :

1. download and install dlib.whl x64 or x86
2. download and install cmake app and add it to path
3. pip install cmake
4. pip install dlib only on python 3.6 to 3.7 with ".whl" file
5. pip install face_recognotion

enjoy face_recognition

Answer (score 0):

My Env details :

> python 3.7 &
> ubuntu 16.04

---

**1)** Assign root permission and update ubuntu first

```
sudo su
apt-get update
```

**2)** Check your version & path for python & pip.

```
which python3

python3 -V

which pip3

pip3 -V
```

**3)**

```
pip3 install cmake
```

**4)**

```
apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    grapgicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagic-dev \
    libatlas-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    software-properties-common \
    zip
```

**6)**

```
apt-get install python3-dev
```

**5)**

```
pip3 install dlib
```

**6)**

```
pip3 install face_recognition
```

---

✅ Done

Answer (score 0):

I just overcame the challenge. You can let VS Code do the hard work for you.

1. Download Visual Studio 2022.
2. When installing, make sure to install **Desktop Development with C++**. It automatically downloads CMake.
3. Once it is complete, clone face_recognition. Simply navigate to a folder of your choice in Command Prompt or Bash and type

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git
   ```
4. Create a new virtual environment for easy differentiation and activate it
5. Install CMake using

   ```
   pip install cmake
   ```
6. Navigate back to the folder where the face_recognition was cloned and enter the command.

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

Note: It is important that you are in the folder where the face_recognition was cloned as it contains the setup.py file.

This takes some time but once complete, you will have face_recogntion installed on your virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. I have installed CMake but it shows the same problem.
This is the solution that worked for me,

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30968699)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple steps:-**

1. install python 3.8 [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/)
2. `pip install cmake` (or) `pip3 install cmake` (#make sure you installing cmake on python3.8 pip)
3. download cmake softwre [here](https://cmake.org/downloads)

4.install c,c++ build tools [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

5.once you install c++ inside the visual studio 1.9GB restart your computer

6.`pip install face_recognition`

Everything done enjoy programming